# unable to use react-native-vector-icons in snack expo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm, expo

I am trying to run this code on my snack expo:

https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/graceful-pretzels

but it keeps giving me an error on the export that:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

```
Cannot find module 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'.
```

Same goes for `react-native-size-matters`. Why can't I use these in my online project? I also tried changing their versions in the package.json but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use it using `@expo/vector-icons`
[expo vector icons](https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/)